# Use an interface to query MongoDB in Spring + Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a user collection in Mongo:

```
{
        "_id" : "user1",
        "_class" : "edu.asu.spring.herckules.domain.impl.User",
        "password" : "99fd6396-a9a3-4c7d-8c1e-f834d99bdc9e",
}
{
        "_id" : "user2",
        "_class" : "edu.asu.spring.herckules.domain.impl.User",
        "password" : "075d743d-32ee-4193-bb6f-0e827bebc34e",
}
```

The corresponding java class and interface with just the getters and setters:

```
public class User implements IUser{

@Id
private String username;
private String password;

@Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

@Override
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}

@Document(collection = "user")
public interface IUser {

public abstract void setUsername(String username);

public abstract String getPassword();

public abstract void setPassword(String password);

public abstract String getUsername();

}
```

Now for example, lets say I am trying to find a list of user objects based on a list of user ids.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

//Inside method
List<String> useridList = new ArrayList<String>();
useridList.add("user1");
useridList.add("user2");
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("username").in(useridList));
List<IUser> usersList = mongoTemplate.find(query, IUser.class);
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property username found on edu.asu.spring.herckules.domain.IUser!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:199)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:560)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:486)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1480)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:527)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:518)
```

I tried to use @TypeAlias as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981195/1664362) but that did not solve my problem. Is there no way I can use an interface in the find query?

Thanks guys.

Comment: And to just let you know...your methods in your interface by default abstract and you don't have specify abstract for each method in your interface.

Comment: I think you @Document(collection = "user") should be declared in the POJO class which is your User Class instead on having it in your Interface. And you have to change your code in the find method to map to User.class

Comment: I understand that using Document annotation on the User class works. My question, is there a way where I can use the interfaces with Document annotation and also use the same interface in the find method?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your interface will have methods and your POJO will have fields which will be mapped to the fields in your mongo document. When you query using Find you are mapping data from Mongo document to your POJO class...I am confused on why or how you want to map your data to methods in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring your `@Document(collection="user")` in the POJO class which is your User Class  instead of having it in your interface.

[Link to Spring Data MongoDB](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html)

Code from Spring Data Mongo Reference.

```
  package com.mycompany.domain;

@Document
public class User{

  @Id
  private String username;
  private String password;

... getter/setters
}
```

And then you can use Spring Data Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, String> {

      User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);

}
```

Thats all you have to do. Now you can inject your UserRepository in any class that you want to find a `User` record

For example if you have a class like below and want to know if a user is present in the DB

```
@Component
public class AnyClass{
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepo;

public boolean findUser(String userName, String password){
boolean flag="false";
User user=userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(userName,password);
if(user!=null){
   flag='true';
}
return flag;

}

}
```

And to add more you can create an Interface and have your custom implementation.
For example

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryCustome {
public void setUsername(String username);
}
```

Your Implementation

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustome {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    public void setUsername(String username){
   //code to set the user name
  } 
}
```

now you can access  `setUsername` by `@Autowired  UserRepository userRepo;`